# Access 2000 Front end is opening in design mode by default

Tags: ms-access

I am having an access 2000 front end. When i double click it, it is openning in design mede. But i want it to open in run mode only. It should open the form is design mode only when i click on mdb file, by pressing SHIFT key.
Can some one please assist me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to set the "start-up" options to display a default form on open, or alternatively you could create the "Autoexec" macro if you have more custom tasks to carry out on start-up.